# Encoding Parameters In Nethereum

Tags: nethereum

I'm trying to encode some parameters and I've noticed all the encoders in the ABI project.
Essentially, I want the equivalent to `abi.encodeParameter(type, value)` in Nethereum? Is there an easy solution to obtaining this with the parameter attributes on the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode them like this, ParameterEncoder is in the namespace `Nethereum.ABI.FunctionEncoding`

```
 public byte[] GetABIParamsEncoded<T>(T functionInput)
 {
            var type = typeof(T);
            return new ParametersEncoder().EncodeParametersFromTypeAttributes(type, functionInput);
  }
```

This simpler function will be available in 3.1 in the ABIEncode class

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what I was looking for will update if so

```
 var encoder = new ConstructorCallEncoder();  
 var result = encoder.EncodeRequest<datamodel>(datamodel, "");
```

Comment: Yes that achieves it as the ConstructorCallEncoder, does not have any signature :)